# SQL Server - update on-the-fly added column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I used the following command to add a new column initialized with "100" to the result of SELECT

```
select id, 100 as newcol from table
```

How to update newcol values? for example I want to set newcol = 200 where id = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a `CASE` statement, like:

```
SELECT id,
       (CASE WHEN id=1 THEN 200 ELSE 100 END) AS NewCol
...
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, case when id = 1 then 200 else 100 end as newcol from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The column isn't created on the table, it just exists in the resultset.

You can do calculations in it though, or use case statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want select different values based on Id.

```
 select id, case 
when id = 1  then 100
when Id = 2 then 200 end
 as newcol from table
```

I have not tested this, but probably this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case "newcol" when id=1 then "newcol" =200
```